# IBrokers: How to assign trail amount for order type 'TRAIL'?

Tags: programming, interactive-brokers, order

I'm using R package [IBrokers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/) with IB TWS.

I'm trying to create a twsOrder object using twsOrder function:

```
twsOrder(...., orderType  = 'TRAIL', ...)
```

How can I assign trail amount?

Comment: Very strange ... from the documentation it looks like trailingAmt is not an allowed parameter in twsOrder() ...